# Switch from POP up window to original window selenium python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I am using below code.At line 0 I called my website url, Line no 1 I clicked on image which opens a popup (2nd IE session) and then I handle the pop up using line 3,4,5,6
After that in pop up IE I did some work like providing name as alpha.

Now my problem is that I have to close this pop up(2nd IE session ) and focus need to switch on my first IE i,e to the line 0,1 UI. 
How this can be possible?

```
0            self.driver.get(url[0]+"abc.com")
1            self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type=\"image\"]").click()
2            time.sleep(15)
3            parent_h = self.driver.current_window_handle
4            handles = self.driver.window_handles # before the pop-up window closes
5            handles.remove(parent_h)
6            self.driver.switch_to_window(handles.pop())
7        self.driver.find_element_by_id("name").clear()
8           self.driver.find_element_by_id("name").send_keys(alpha)
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have it:

```
self.driver.close()
self.driver.switch_to_window(parent_h)
```

Comment: but before moving to self.driver.switch_to_window(parent_h) , I have to close the 2nd IE session